# Don't understand algorithmic of string to list of words function

Tags: python, string, algorithm

This is a Python function. It's convert to a list of words from a string. But I don't understand the algorithmic the part of code:

```
for c in ch:
        if c==" ":
            lista.append(ct) # add to list of temporary string
            ct=""            # the ch temporary string reinicialization
```

I don't understand, how the ct can append to the list, because the ct=""? How casn it get value?

Thanks for the help!

Here the full code of function:

```
def szoLista(ch):
    "a ch karakterláncot átalakítja szavakból álló listává"
    lista, ct=[],""     # ct átmeneti string
    for c in ch:
        if c==" ":
            lista.append(ct) # a listához adjuk a ch átmenei stringet
            ct=""            # a ch átmeneti string reinicializálása
        else:
            ct=ct+c
    if ct !="":
        lista.append(ct)    # az utolsó szó hozzáadása
    return lista
```

Comment: This is a terrible function in the first place - `ch.split(' ')` would do the same thing, but faster and more understandably.

Comment: Also you should use only English in code examples. Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else:
    ct=ct+c
```

These are the lines you are overlooking.
`ct` is set empty when a space if found, but after it was already added to the list.
If the current character is not a space, the character is appended to `ct`.
So when you encounter  the next space, you have the last word in `ct` and can add it to the list.

Comment: thanks, I have never meet when the for start with the whitespace analysis, in string, cause the string never start with the whitespace. And I, yes overlooking the else clause, and just concatreate to the if clause. This was me strange.

Answer (score 2):

ct is not an empty string - ct equal to word because you have ct = ct + c in else clause.

However think that your code can be easily modified to use [str.split function](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split):

```
text = 'word1 word2 word3'
text.split() # ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

Edited:

Or depending on what you really need(sample below returns the same result as your function):

```
text = ' word1  word2 word3 '
text.rstrip(' ').split(' ') # ['', 'word1', '', 'word2', 'word3']
```

Note that you can use strip(' ')  to remove all leading and trailing white spaces if needed.

Comment: thanks the sample with split(''). I know that it is better for this job, but in the exercise have to do this without split()

Answer (score 1):

```
def szoLista(ch):
    lista, ct=[],"" #    lista for storing the result, ct for current word
    for c in ch: # read string char by char
        if c==" ": # if current char is space
            lista.append(ct) # append current word for to the resulting list
            ct=""            # clear current word (ready to constructing the next one)
        else: # if current char is any other char
            ct=ct+c # append it to current word

    # we haven't appended the last recorded word, so let's do it (if it's not empty)
    if ct !="":
        lista.append(ct)
    return lista
```